# How do I divert rain water that collects between two shed structures?

Tags: waterproofing, gutters, shed

I have a pvc hoop shed that sits against the rear of my main resin storage shed. The rainwater flows down the taut tarp of the hoop shed & gets into the main shed floor. What's the best method to divert the water away?

[Resin storage shed](http://www.homedepot.com/p/US-Leisure-Keter-Stronghold-10-ft-x-8-ft-Resin-Storage-Shed-157479/100652232)

Hoop Shed: (older pic that still shows how hoop shed is flush to resin shed on one side and deer fencing on the other)

[image: hoop shed:]

Comment: Do you think the water enters the resin shed through the wall or corners, or is it pooling on the ground and running in through the base?

Comment: Leave a gap between the two?

Comment: thanks jphi1618  .   hmmm, good question. the shed is raised a few inches off the ground so i dont think it's pooling beneath the floor. i have yet to see water enter it but my best guess is it's entering where the wall meets the floor. i did put silicone caulk at that juncture after assembling the resin shed but maybe the weight on the floor has caused a break in the caulk seal.

Answer (score 1):

i would wedge a length of plastic gutter on a slight slope between the 2 sheds , making a small gap and encouraging the water to run into the gutter and into a down pipe directing it away from both sheds. You may have to experiment a little for the height of this

Answer (score 0):

Since, you already have one tarp, why not have 2? Put another tarp over the gap by screwing the new tarp to the shed's sides after running over the ridge. Then, run it down the right side of hoops where you can wire tie it without puncturing the existing tarp.

Of course, you could get a bigger tarp. Run it over the ridge & even all the way down the shed sides & then repeat what you did on the hoops. Use the original tarp somewhere else, as a floor &/or doors for the hoop structure. Or. string it up to those posts on your right to double your home's size...kidding, who would live under a tarp when they have a shed.

Which, leads me to. Get or make a bigger shed.

Answer (score 0):

Moving either shed makes the most sense to me.  Both don't look that hard to move.  If you don't want to do that maybe try bending a piece of aluminum on a brake and flash it against the shed and cut it under the blue tarp to catch the water.  I would move one or the other shed.